# VLOOKUP to match multiple Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, multiple-columns, vlookup

I have been trying to match multiple columns then paste the result after matching.

Here is the formula

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR({"Formula";IF(A2:A1000="",, VLOOKUP(A2:A1000&B2:B1000&C2:C1000&D2:D1000&E2:E1000,{Sheet2!A2:A1000&Sheet2!B2:B1000&Sheet2!C2:C1000,Sheet2!D2:D1000,Sheet2!E2:E1000 }, 6, 0) )})), 1000, 1)
```

Same Data is available in sheet2 but additionally with Column 6 values i want to paste Column 6 values into Sheet1 Column 6 after matching. I have tried to get where i am wrong but could not fetch the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1211G_LhgpgNjTcoNrIIdpSXRdL8HiDR7nLOz1R5WtTY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the combination of first and last name will be unique you can try

```
={"HEADER TITLE"; ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B, Sheet2!F:F}, 2, 0),))}
```

If you want to match all values in the range A:E, please try

```
={"HEADER TITLE"; ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D&E2:E, {Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C&Sheet2!D:D&Sheet2!E:E, Sheet2!F:F}, 2, 0),))}
```